# How to make crud operation in asp.net mvc aspx without database nor entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

All tutorials I can find is with database or entity framework. I just want a simple class as model with field creation and update from the view and using .aspx template.

Can somebody give me as simplest example as possible or point me an article on the web I've bee googling all day long without finding any.

Comment: You can always use ado.net directly, not sure what you are looking for exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use an EF Code First tutorial and remove the calls to `DbContext` - without `DbContext`, the entities are simply POCOs.  Replace those calls with however you plan to persist/read your data.